# HTML form - keep reference to uploaded file for 2 button options

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

I have an html form and 2 php files, all of which work well. In the form I created a preview button that references a php file that shows the uploaded cvs in an html table as a preview. The submit button inserts it into  a database.

I would like to have the form contain one button that goes to the preview page and once the info is confirmed, there would be another button that references the submitted file, but I can't seem to get that to work.

Due to the environment I'm trying to get this to work without javascript or ajax if possible, as another user gave me a javascript option.

Here is the html form:

```
<form method="post" action="confirm.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label>Upload File</label>
 <input type="file" name="file">

 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Confirm" >
 </form>


 <form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label>Upload File</label>
 <input type="file" name="file">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

Each Php file corresponds as well:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

Is there any way to go from upload to preview to submit and keep reference to $file?

Comment: you'll need to use sessions for this

Comment: I'm familiar with starting a session in php and declaring variables but how would I use that in this instance? And would it only be on the html form page, or each php page?

Comment: for each page. Assign a session array to a post array and for the 2nd form,  a hidden input would probably do the trick also.

Comment: Thank you,  i will give this a try!